# Loop function and add columns to dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, loops, mean, sapply

I want to loop a function over dataframes and add information from the function to the data frame. I have read the many relevant posts on looping and applying functions to dataframes that have got me close to what I need, but not quite there, so Im hoping people can help me.

I have a number of dataframes that look like this

```
dat1=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
dat2=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
dat3=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
```

I want to calculate the mean of some of these columns and add on to the end of the dataframe. So, I wrote a function to calculate means from a dataframe:

```
my_fun <-  function(dataframe){
rowMeans( dataframe[ , c("V1","V2")],na.rm=TRUE) 
}
```

To apply this function to one dataframe, I do this:

```
 dat1$V6<- my_fun(dat1)
```

But I want to be able to loop through all dataframes and add this mean column on to the end of each df.

After reading some helpful posts, I created a list and used sapply:

```
dfList<-list(dat1,dat2,dat3)#create list
sapply(dfList, my_fun) #apply function to list
```

Which gives me the values that I want, but I dont want them in a separate output- I'd like them to simply add a column on to the original dataframe- as happens when I apply the function to the individual dataframes. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Or point me to a post that describes how to do this (I have searched high and low, but maybe typing the wrong keywords) Im sure its very straightforward if you know how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Just to clear the confusion.

```
dat1=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
dat5=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
dat7=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))

my_fun <-  function(dataframe){
rowMeans( dataframe[ , c("V1","V2")],na.rm=TRUE) 
}

dfList<-list(dat1,dat5,dat7)

Vars <- grep("dat", ls(), value=TRUE)
Vars
 #[1] "dat1" "dat5" "dat7"

res <- lapply(dfList, function(x) transform(x,V6=my_fun(x)))
for(i in 1:length(Vars)){
assign(Vars[i], res[[i]],envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

A Second function:

```
my_funSD <-  function(dataframe){
apply( dataframe[ , c("V1","V2")],1,sd) 
}

dfList<-list(dat1,dat5,dat7)
res1 <- lapply(dfList, function(x) transform(x,V7=my_funSD(x)))
ncol(dat1)
 #[1] 6

for(i in 1:length(Vars)){
assign(Vars[i], res1[[i]],envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
ncol(dat1)
#[1] 7
colnames(dat1)
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" "V7"
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for your speedy response. This works perfectly if my dfs go up in number sequentially, as in my example. However, often I have missing dfs e.g. it starts from dat3, then dat 4, then dat7. Ive tried changing the Vars to reflect this but cant quite get it to work.

Comment: Hi 'user2351480'.  Suppose i start a fresh session with 'dat1' "dat5', "dat7".  After applying your function and creating dfList, the output of ls() would be:  ls()
[1] "dat1"   "dat5"   "dat7"   "dfList" "my_fun"
 grep("dat", ls(), value=TRUE)
[1] "dat1" "dat5" "dat7"
Vars <- grep("dat", ls(), value=TRUE).  I was able to get the result using the for() loop.

Comment: Hi again Arkun- One issue that im having with yours and Davids solution is that if I want to use another function on the dataframes (e.g. report the SD) it seems to overwrite the V6 column, even If I assign it a new name. thanks again and apologies for making this so awkward.

Comment: Hi 'user2351480'.  Have you run dfList <- list(dat1, dat5, dat7) again?  If you haven't, that object is not updated after running the for() loop.  I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

It's soo much easier and at least 100x faster if you use `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(612)
dat1=as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
dat2=as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
dat3=as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))

dtList <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)

for (dat in dtList) {
     dat[,V6:=(V1 + V2)/2]
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
> dtList

[[1]]
           V1         V2         V3         V4          V5          V6
1:  0.3903228 -1.1581608  1.0171311  0.3866628  0.02756137 -0.38391897
2: -0.6030124  0.4713771 -2.4204376 -0.2843527  0.53463600 -0.06581764
3: -0.9850333  0.3343518 -1.2329712 -1.1767533  0.56714483 -0.32534080
4: -0.1591335 -0.6729444  0.5062648 -0.3001857 -0.84896068 -0.41603897
5:  1.7127203  0.3149884  1.7633945  1.7824786 -0.90316850  1.01385434

[[2]]
            V1         V2         V3          V4         V5         V6
1: -1.22790810  0.8429506  0.4921844 -0.29686607 -0.9501956 -0.1924788
2:  0.09405923 -1.6970403  0.1280003  1.22284944  0.8667643 -0.8014905
3:  0.55298783 -0.1081849  0.4120268 -0.56411756  1.9135802  0.2224015
4: -0.82621808  0.4753731  0.4755664 -0.05885804  0.9658787 -0.1754225
5:  0.44262554  0.3036363 -1.7404580  0.88870595  1.4826431  0.3731309

[[3]]
            V1          V2         V3        V4          V5          V6
1:  0.82085834  0.07221027  1.8835042 0.2563714  0.27891033  0.44653430
2:  0.00445113  1.89450534  0.3878858 1.8385587 -1.86381524  0.94947824
3:  0.66458950 -1.31023362 -0.9403257 1.2128128  0.74922668 -0.32282206
4: -1.40169143 -1.52925147  0.8232823 0.3391147  0.33463875 -1.46547145
5:  1.10566340 -1.16512217  0.3859652 0.8123110  0.04712086 -0.02972939
```

Comment: And what exactly that loop of yours gave back? Can you show an output?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. Gave me lot's of errors and `dtList` staid the same

Comment: What errors did you get? It runs fine on my machine, using R 3.1.0 and data.table 1.9.2.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have tried and like David, I also get errors.

Comment: Please, tell me what errors you get, or I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your function so that it assembles the data frame before returning the result.  Then you can use `lapply` with the other data frames.

```
> add.column <-  function(dataframe){
      dataframe$Mean <- rowMeans(dataframe[, c("V1","V2")], na.rm = TRUE) 
      dataframe
  }
> lapply(list(dat1, dat2, dat3), add.column)
[[1]]
          V1          V2          V3          V4         V5       Mean
1  0.3353508  0.01120530  1.24966428 -0.11351381 -0.1004569  0.1732780
2 -0.4815519 -0.06247284 -0.02295877  0.87322960 -0.5307487 -0.2720124
3  0.7600038  1.85289546  0.36312147 -0.02831645 -1.6644752  1.3064496
4  0.1679056  1.27509579  0.80371659 -0.85136078 -0.1014557  0.7215007
5 -1.7393888  0.72481368  0.06583188 -0.61422707  1.7497541 -0.5072876

[[2]]
          V1         V2         V3          V4         V5        Mean
1 -1.5753298 -0.6997616 -0.4343483  0.04134617 -2.3060171 -1.13754567
2  0.1871898 -0.2132065 -0.1839468 -0.29277828  1.6798379 -0.01300837
3 -0.1530399 -1.0674358 -0.2897129 -0.49723256 -1.0571164 -0.61023786
4 -1.5099567  0.4665531 -0.7433692  1.71985447 -0.3236015 -0.52170179
5 -0.6545995 -0.5638415 -0.5925143 -0.10060696  0.1332452 -0.60922051

[[3]]
          V1          V2          V3         V4         V5        Mean
1  0.1716287 -0.09367833  0.12334527 -0.0061906  1.4477591  0.03897519
2 -1.1550710  0.26045021  1.80286581  0.4236090 -0.0848587 -0.44731037
3  0.3735215 -0.70953979 -0.08194104  0.7470116  0.6457781 -0.16800913
4  2.0178667 -0.90537252  1.51190214 -1.0803367  0.7308533  0.55624709
5  0.4143222  0.89980628 -1.87445683 -1.8482057  0.1797795  0.65706422
```

Also, you might want to add a `subset` argument in case you want to take the mean of other subsets later. Something lie this:

```
> add.column <-  function(data, subset)
  {
      data$Mean <- rowMeans(data[, subset], na.rm = TRUE) 
      data
  }
```

Comment: Hi Richard. thanks- this is a very elegant answer. Same question as to david- how do I unsplit the output back to dataframes? apologies for the stupidity of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could use `Map` between `dfList` and your `lapply` function (instead of `sapply`)

```
temp <- Map(cbind, dfList, V6 = lapply(dfList, my_fun)) # Add V6 column to `dfList`

datasnames <- c("dat1","dat2","dat3") # write here the names of your data sets (in the same order they were specified in `dfList`)

names(temp) <- datasnames
list2env(temp, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

**Edit** (Per OPs additional request in comments)

So there could be many ways to do this, one is to modify your function

```
my_fun <-  function(dataframe){
  V6 <- rowMeans( dataframe[ , c("V1","V2")],na.rm=TRUE);
  V7 <- sd(dataframe[, "V1"],na.rm=TRUE)
  return(cbind(V6, V7))
}

temp <- Map(cbind, dfList, lapply(dfList, my_fun)) # Add V6 and V7 columns to `dfList`
names(temp) <- datasnames
list2env(temp, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. Would you be able to show me how to then unsplit the output back into dfs? Im sorry im such a noob to programming and R.

Comment: excellent. thank you very much. One issue that im having with yours and arkuns solution is that if I want to use another function on the dataframes (e.g. report the SD) it seems to overwrite the V6 column, even If I assign it a new name. thanks again and apologies for making this so awkward.

Comment: See my edit above using `list2env` to update your original data sets